# qt5's qss syntax has changed?

Tags: qtstylesheets, qt4.7, qt5.15

Here is a qss statement I wrote in qt4.7.8, now I switched to qt5.15.2 and this statement doesn't seem to work

[image]

Only the first lineInfo object is displayed normally

After testing, it must be changed to the following to display properly

[image]

I don't know what the reason is, is it because the qss syntax has changed?